# Is Monte Carlo Tree Search policy or value iteration (or something else)?

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am taking a Reinforcement Learning class and I didn’t understand how to combine the concepts of policy iteration/value iteration with Monte Carlo (and also TD/SARSA/Q-learning). In the table below, how can the empty cells be filled: Should/can it be binary yes/no, some string description or is it more complicated?

[image]

Comment: Did you construct that table? Although there are similar tables that show relationships between RL approaches, this particular split is not a normal one to investigate because there is IMO no meaningful difference between the techniques. Also, in your title I *think* you mean "Monte Carlo Control" and **not** "Monte Carlo Tree Search" - from the context of your question that would make more sense. You could ask this question about MCTS, so it is not 100% clear, but none of the other algorithms you have listed are quite the same as MCTS (and are similar to Monte Carlo Control).

Comment: Ok thanks it clarifies it a little bit (edit the question if you want to). I also read some more and saw something similar i.e. that MC-control (or whatever it should be called) is not applicable to value/policy iteration whereas TD and all its variants are. Is it correct that the 'rollout' mechanism (like in MC) is considered something paradigmatically different to an 'iterative' mechanism? I'm confused right now since they seem to be overlapping - they both lead to updated state values.

Comment: I cannot edit the question unless I am really sure what you are asking. So far, I am not. MCTS has rollouts, and is typically a planning algorithm. Monte Carlo Control does not have rollouts, and is a learning algorithm. MCTS can be *combined* with some of the other algorithms to create combined learning+planning systems - and yes it does share some concepts with Monte Carlo Control. None of this has much to do with differences between policy iteration and value iteration. I think you need to edit the question so that it asks something coherent that you would like to understand.

Comment: Ok thanks. The reason I'm trying to ask a question about this (and building some nice table that can summarize it) is because I know I'm not alone in thinking this is a bit confusing. But if i understand it correctly you have answered the question by saying it falls under the 'something else' and that the table doesn't make sense/should be 'more complicated'.

Comment: There are important differences between RL value-based algorithms. Bootstrapping vs sampling, on-policy vs off-policy, single-step vs multi-step etc etc. But relationship to value iteration vs policy iteration is not really a thing here. So I would say that the table does not make sense. If you had some other factor, such as bootstrapping vs sampling, you could show something interesting.